# in which array is the value I'm looking for?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two or more than two arrays in PHP. For example:

```
$array1 = [1,5,10,15,22,28];
$array2 = [1,8,12,16,25,30];
$array3 = [10,15,20,21,22];
```

I want to find which of these arrays contains the value 5, so that I can create the output "$array1 contains 5"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried too much but ı couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Try using the [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) method

Comment: What if your search value is in more than one array i.e. `22`

Comment: Hi @Ikdhruw, I' m improving a vehicle assignment system. So, I have a lot of drivers, vehicles, and time schedules.

Comment: Made the question more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
$array1 = [1,5,10,15,22,28];
$array2 = [1,8,12,16,25,30];
$array3 = [10,15,20,21,22];
$f = 5;

for($n=1;$n<=3;$n++){
    if(in_array($f, ${"array" . $n})){
        echo "\$array$n contains $f";
    }
}
```

**Edit different variable name**

```
$zomer = [1,5,10,15,22,28];
$halil = [1,8,12,16,25,30];
$kaya= [10,15,20,21,22]; 
$f = 5;
$collection = compact("zomer","halil","kaya");

foreach ($collection as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($f, $collection[$key])){
        echo "\$$key contains $f";
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @Zar Ni Ko Ko, I have one simple question about the array issue above. My arrays are not like this,
$array1 = [1,5,10,15,22,28];
$array2 = [1,8,12,16,25,30];
$array3 = [10,15,20,21,22];

actually they are like this.

$zomer= [1,5,10,15,22,28];
$halil= [1,8,12,16,25,30];
$kaya= [10,15,20,21,22];
.... etc ..

How can solve it? I have been working for days but I couldn't solve this matter.

Comment: @Bos , I edited my answer , I hope this will help again .

Comment: Dear @Zar Ni Ko Ko, thank you so much for your kind assist. It's working :)

Answer (score 0):

As said @KrijnToet, it could be done easy with help of [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

```
if(in_array($val, $array1)) echo $val.' comes from $array1'.PHP_EOL;
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/MNvI3)**

Comment: Thanks, @aksenP but we suppose that we have 100 arrays. we connot write one by one  like "if(in_array($val, $array1)) echo $val.' comes from $array1'.PHP_EOL;"

Comment: @BilalSungur, provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines may help:

feed the function `findVal()` with the arrays and a `needle` value you're looking for and it will return the name of the array(s) holding it.

```
<?php
$array1 = [1, 5, 10, 15, 22, 28];
$array2 = [1, 8, 12, 16, 25, 30];
$array3 = [10, 15, 20, 21, 22];

findVal([$array1, $array2, $array3], 30);

function findVal($arrays = [], $needle)
{
    foreach ($arrays as $key => $array) {
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            if ($value == $needle) {
                foreach ($GLOBALS as $arrayName => $value) {
                    if ($value === $array) {
                        echo 'value ' . $needle . ' found in : ' . $arrayName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`$GLOBALS` — References all variables available in global scope, so we can use it to retrieve the array name(s).

[demo](https://3v4l.org/bCU2Z)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array1 = [1,5,10,15,22,28];
$array2 = [1,8,12,16,25,30];
$array3 = [10,15,20,21,22];

$compacted = compact('array1', 'array2', 'array3');

$needle = 21;
$found = array_filter($compacted, function($item) use ($needle) {
    return in_array($needle, $item);
});

var_export(array_keys($found));
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'array3',
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using this function we can search in any number of array

```
$array1 = [1,5,10,15,22,28];
$array2 = [1,8,12,16,25,30];
$array3 = [10,15,20,21,22];
$findval=5;
$arrayFinal = array('array1' =>$array1 ,'array2' =>$array2 ,'array3' =>$array3 );
function searchForId($find, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key=> $value) {
      if(in_array($find, $value)){
         echo "\$$key contains $find";
      }
   }
}
searchForId($findval,$arrayFinal); //Call function
```